# Spring + H2 embedded sql script not running properly

Tags: spring, h2

I am working on a pure spring project and attempting to use h2 as an embedded database. Here is what my definition looks like:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:create-db.sql" />
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

There are no errors in the console as it reads:

```
ScriptUtils:442 - Executing SQL script from class path resource [create-db.sql]
```

Here is what my **create-db.sql** looks like:

```
DROP TABLE account IF EXISTS;

CREATE TABLE account (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(30),
    email  VARCHAR(50)
);
```

I initialize a swing manager by using the following:

```
<bean depends-on="dataSource" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingBean">
    <property name="targetClass" value="org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManagerSwing" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="main" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>--url</value>
            <!-- <value>jdbc:hsqldb:memory:oa</value> -->
            <value>jdbc:h2:mem:oa</value>
            <value>--user</value>
            <value>sa</value>
            <value>--password</value>
            <value></value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

There are no tables, no data... any ideas what could be causing this or how to effectively troubleshoot?

Comment: why using ***oa*** here? jdbc:h2:mem:oa. It is jdbc:h2:mem:testdb by default

Comment: You were right, I wasn't using the correct name. The correct name in my case was **dataSource**.

Answer (score 0):

The script was running however I was not connected to the correct instance. With logging I was able to find the right name:

`Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:dataSource;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false'`

In my case it was **dataSource**